# uploading locally customized Wordpress theme to live serve - do changes show up?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wordpress-theming

I'm working with a wordpress theme that has very little customization available without making the theme "active". I already have content on the live wordpress site and don't want to spend a lot of time in "maintenance" mode.

I'm wondering however if I were to customize the site fully on an local server - MAMP - and upload the theme files and plugins that have been customized on the local server, will the changes appear on the live version of the site? Or will I have to activate the theme on the live site to make the changes.

I wouldn't want to have to upload databases or anything like that since it's already set up on the live server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make changes locally on WAMP/MAMP and upload those changed theme files to your live server, they'll automatically get updated. If the theme you're editing is active, they'll show up. If another theme is active, they won't.

Let's say you've got `cool-theme` activated on your MAMP site locally. If every page and post has an `the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );` at the top, and you change it to `the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' );` locally. If you upload those changes via FTP or SSH to your live server, if `cool-theme` is activated, the changes will happen immediately. You don't have to deactivate/reactivate anything to make the changes happen.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was wondering. So, a bit more complicated, many themes use plugins to change the appearance one way or another in conjunction with the built in theme functionality. Visual Composer for instance is on a ton of sites, so if I were to make changes to the site using plugins like that, or even customizer on wordpress, if I then uploaded those changed plugin/theme files, would the changes remain? or would they reset?

Answer (score 1):

Your LIVE and LOCAL servers are two separate servers with different databases. Usually developers edit/write/test all files on your LOCAL and once finished, they transfer all changed/new files to the LIVE server.

So No the changes you make on your LOCAL won't change on your LIVE server unless you transferred the files via FTP